# How to Perf test a SOAP Post action using Gatling

Tags: soap, gatling

I have a question about testing a SOAP post method using gatling..for example i would like to know how to write a gatling script for below ,is it possible in Gatling?

```
POST http://services.online.local:4059/Business/EventReporterV2 HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: "http://fakeurl.com/Service/2013- 
03/IStandardEndpoint/GetServiceVersion"
Host: r20services.onlinegaming.local:4059
Content-Length: 161
Expect: 100-continue
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive

<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Body>
<GetServiceVersion xmlns="http://fakeurl.com/Service/2013-03"/>
</s:Body>
 </s:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it possible. You can test it just like post method with SOAP headers and use request body from file `.body(ElFileBody(requestBodyFilePath)).asXML`